# Trouble installing scikit-learn on Windows 7 machine

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I installed sci-kit learn with the installer scikit-learn-0.13.1.win32-py2.7.exe but when I try to call it in Canopy and iPython I get the following error: "ImportError: No module named sklearn".

I tried the following solutions found online but non of them work

- Running python setup.py install in the directory and got this error:  "ImportError: no module named sklearn._build_utils"
- Tried pip install - U scikit-learn but the download keeping on timing out
- Tried easy_install - U scikit-learn but the download also kept on timing out

I'm wondering if it is because I am using Canopy (Free version) and I should maybe uninstall it and install all my packages again using vanilla Python.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding sklearn to your python path manually? Have a look at this thread, it might help!

[How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)